# Why is overshadowing not supported with Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I've been trying to work with Codename One for years, but I still find errors that prevent me from releasing my apps.

Locally I can fix errors by I overshadowing erroneous classes. This works but for some reason it doesn't work when I send my apps to the build server.

If I could overshadow faulty classes would be good in many ways:

1. I'd better get on with my work
2. I could check how my corrections work on the different platforms
3. I could contribute to the further development of Codename One

I suffer much from not being able to publish my apps because I see no way how I can fix basic problems.

I love iPhones and do not like the Mac. Therefore I do not own a Mac and prefer to work with Linux and use the Codename One build server.

What are the reasons for not supporting overloading classes like `com.codename1.ui.Component`? Can You see that it would be beneficial?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the first time people asked for that but we won't deliver it. Doing this creates **huge** problems:

- Developers don't file issues or submit fixes instead they make local fixes
- Developers break things due to complex behaviors then try to get support and blame us for the issues

We have a process of [submitting patches to Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html), patches are always accepted quickly when they are valid. If something needs fixing that's what you need to do. If you need a hack then submit a patch that defines the extension point that you need. That's why we are open source...

In the past this might have been painful as you would need to wait until we updated the servers, but since changes go in every week in recent revisions this is no longer an issue. Don't think of it as "contributing", think of it as free code reviews where the entire community pulls together to improve your work...

Comment: Yes, working with Condename One has been daunting in the past - and it is still so. Look at "Drop target container does not scroll reasonably on dragFinished # 1994". I can not use drag and drop - what now? My issues usually do not get priority and they are closed without comment. For a long time I had a paid subscription and it has its reason why this is no longer so. I think you should rethink your point of view? Your arguments are void.

Comment: What I need is a working platform. I do not want any patches. I want reliable releases for reliable build processes and am willing to pay for them. And, of course, I want to be able to correct existing errors myself, even if the path I've taken is only patchwork and is not (yet) suitable for integration into Codename One.

Comment: And, yes, I would like to make suggestions immediately instead of reporting errors. But if I have no chance to get ahead with my project, my motivation tends towards zero

Comment: You are spending a lot of effort submitting issues, issues are things that someone needs to spend an equivalent or possibly larger amount of time evaluating and following up on. We have thousands of users and need to follow up on hundreds of contacts per day! Instead if you just submit a pull request which is effectively "edit the Codename One source code"  you'd get a faster result for less effort and you don't need to pay... We close issues on some cases by mistake, you can comment below and clarify that this issue isn't resolved and we'll reopen said issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not an expert enough to do your work. And that should not be necessary either.

Comment: About closing error reports: Please start to comment on the reason for closing the respective error report.

Comment: I think it is a serious mistake that you do not allow any error corrections to basic components. Getting rid of all the workarounds that are necessary to work withCodename One now would be incentive enough to contribute to Codename One. If you make my work impossible, you do not help anybody

Comment: Can you point at an issue where it was closed without prior discussion or a commit? If so that might be a mistake. Overshadowing is by definition "doing our work", you would literally replace our code with yours so it's hard for me to see how this would be different than what I suggested. This is an open source project, it's doing "our work" as in the communities work (everyone's), You are pointing at "basic" components but we have no way of knowing what you changed so the idea that we can separate this doesn't make sense. We do offer a way, a pull request... I still don't see the problem

Comment: Just noticed I neglected to answer your comment on being "expert enough". I've read enough of your questions/issues to see that you know full well what to do and could probably do a pull request with a hand tied behind your back... I think you just never tried it before and it might look like it's more work/trouble than overshadowing when in fact the opposite is true.

Comment: I certainly could do a pull request whilst not knowing what I was doing. For example  "Drop target container does not scroll reasonably on dragFinished # 1994" I certainly know what causes trouble in my app but I do not know why this code sits there. On one hand I am ready to assume somebody has written the code with best knwledge and intentions - on the other hand I cannot make any sense out of it. I just do not feel capaple of judging the consequences of changing inner workings of the Component class apart from my use cases.

Comment: Notice that this is a post about overshadowing. If you overshadow code without understanding why it is there then you are in the same position of risking unforeseeable side effects and relying on implementation details that might change without any warning... This is a slippery slope, you might be responsible with this but you do understand that once we put something like that out people will abuse it and overshadow the entire SDK creating immense cascading issues.

Comment: But if I had the option I could get on further with my apps and at least could prove that a fix works well with those.

Comment: You can run the app locally and change the classpath locally to debug/prove that's demonstrated in the video I linked in the answer. That's how we debug Codename One and fix it.

Comment: That is what I have done. But obviously I have used this particular feature in a way nobody else has done it before - for example drag and drop. Otherwise the problem would have arisen long before I discovered it. I do not have the necessary skills, test cases and experiences which would be required to say a change would be suitable to go into the standard. But probably I'm being stupid and should just do it as you say to get something done. See I desperately need a solution but don't know whether it is suited for Codename One as a whole.

Comment: That's why we are here, if you get something wrong during the pull request process we'll help/fix. If you break someone's use case as a result of this then he submits a pull request to fix that and so forth. That's the beauty of open source.